# assign array values to separate class values

Tags: php, arrays, oop, class

I have a configuration.php as a separate file.IT contat bellow pardFactory class with 11 variables.I need to assign their values from  array.that $ConfigData is in another file.How would i do this?

CLASS

```
   <?php 
     class PardFactory { 
     public $TITLE = 'Sri lanka Accommodation';
     public $ONLINE = 'Site Online';
     public $OFFLINE =  '';
     public $EMAIL =  '';
     public $METADESCRIPTION =   '';
     public $METAKEYWORDS =  '';
     public $COPYRIGHT =  '';
     public $HOST =  '';
     public $DATABASE =  '';
     public $USERNAME =  '';
     public $PASSWORD =  '';
     } 
     ?>
```

ARRAY

```
$ConfigData = array($adminConfig->TITLE,
 $adminConfig->ONLINE,
 $adminConfig->OFFLINE,
 $adminConfig->EMAIL,
 $adminConfig->METADESCRIPTION,
 $adminConfig->METAKEYWORDS,
 $adminConfig->COPYRIGHT,
 $adminConfig->HOST,
 $adminConfig->DATABASE,
 $adminConfig->USERNAME,
 $adminConfig->PASSWORD);
```

I want to pass array values to class values.

Also, I need to have only that above pardFactory class in that configuration.php. IF i'd do like above i need to include pardFactory class to the configuration.php first. I need to have this file like joomla configuration.php file

Answer (score 0):

Do this create an object of class file like this:

```
$obj = new PardFactory($ConfigData);
```

And create a constructor

```
function __construct($config) {
    $this->TITLE = $config->TITLE;
    $this->ONLINE = $config->ONLINE;
}
```

and so on.

Comment: i need to have only that  above pardFactory class in that configuration.php..IF i'll do like above i need to include pardFactory class to the  configuration.php first.I need to have this file like joomla configuration.php  file

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  $obj = new PardFactory($ConfigData);

class PardFactory {
public function __construct(Array $config=array()){
  foreach($config as $key => $value){
    $this->{$key} = $value;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: i need to have only that above pardFactory class in that configuration.php..IF i'll do like above i need to include pardFactory class to the configuration.php first.I need to have this file like joomla configuration.php file